# Why is $\vec{L}_P$ time dependent?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

**Question:**  A small mass $m$ is attached to a massless string whose other end is fixed at $P$ as shown in the figure. The mass
is undergoing circular motion is the $x$-$y$ plane with centre at $O$ and constant angular speed $\omega$. If the angular momentum of the system, calculated about $O$ and $P$ are denoted by $\vec{L_O}$ and $\vec{L_P}$ respectively

[image]

I Could figure out the $\vec{L_O}$ will be independent on time but answer says that It's not the case with $\vec{L_P}$. **But Why so?** shouldn't it be simply time independent too when everything is constant?

Comment: Write out the position vector for the mass relative to the point P and use the definition of angular momentum.

Comment: By angular momentum, you mean $L_p=m(r\times v)$ Right? @CAF

Comment: Use $\mathbf L_P = \mathbf r_P \times \mathbf p,$ where $\mathbf p = m \dot{\mathbf r}$,  and $\dot{\mathbf r}$ is the velocity vector of the mass in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others interested, I'll just post an answer. Relative to $O$, we have $$\mathbf L_O = \mathbf r_O \times \mathbf p = m \mathbf r_O \times \dot{\mathbf r}$$ where $\mathbf r_O = a\hat r$ and $\dot{\mathbf r} = a \dot\theta \hat \theta$, so that $ \mathbf L_O = ma^2 \dot\theta \hat z$ which is manifestly constant because $\dot \theta = \omega$ is and $\hat z$ is the *fixed* cartesian unit vector.

However, relative to $P$, the position vector of the mass acquires an additional component in the $\hat z$ direction, $$\mathbf r_P = \ell \cos \phi \hat z + a \hat r,$$ where $\ell$ is the length of the string and $\dot{\mathbf r}$ is still the same velocity vector in polar coordinates used previously $\dot{\mathbf r} = a \dot\theta \hat \theta$. Their cross product generates terms proportional to $\hat r$ and $\hat z$, the former of course is *not* a fixed unit vector, giving rise to time dependency in the angular momentum about $P$.